# How to create option menu for listview item in android?

Tags: android, listview, optionmenu

In my application, i want to create a option menu for each item of listview, it's look like following link image. Thank for helping!
[image: Image Link]

Comment: have to tried to google at first?

Comment: try google first.. or androidhive.. Give it some effort then if any problem arises you can ask a question here. Don't expect that complete source codes will be provided here.

Answer (score 1):

That looks very close to a Spinner ( http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html ). Although I have not tried, I am sure there is a way to have a spinner perform actions using the OnItemSelected class similar to a listview. Simply populate it how you want and take the returned position to run a specific function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Expandable listview in android..
You can check the this
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: I dont think Expandable listview can do this, I think custom view with pinner will be better but i dont know how to deploy it, help me if u know, thankyou